# Selenium Node failed to register with the hub

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7-x64, selenium-grid

I ran the command below on machine as a hub(IP Addr:192.168.55.209, OS:Ubuntu):

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar \ -role hub -port 4444
```

Then I ran another command below on another machine as a node(OS: Windows 7 64bit):

```
java -jar "selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar" \ -role node -port 5555 -hub http://192.168.55.209:4444/grid/register \browser browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS
```

But I got error message below: Please help find what's the problem. (I've disabled the firewall)

```
> Nov 05, 2012 5:12:37 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
> INFO: Launching a selenium grid node Nov 05, 2012 5:12:38 PM
> org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.SelfRegisteringRemote startRemoteServer
> WARNING: error getting the parameters from the hub. The node may end
> up with wrong timeouts.A JSONObject text must begin  with '{' at
> character 1 17:12:38.064 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 23.3-b01
> 17:12:38.066 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64 17:12:38.068 INFO -
> v2.25.0, with Core v2.25.0. Built from revision 17482 17:12:38.172
> INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to:
> http://127.0.0.1:5555/wd/hub 17:12:38.174 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
> 17:12:38.174 INFO - Started
> HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
> 17:12:38.175 INFO - Started
> HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server] 17:12:38.175 INFO -
> Started HttpContext[/,/] 17:12:38.177 INFO - Started
> org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@508969c3 17:12:38.177
> INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd] 17:12:38.181 INFO - Started
> SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:5555 17:12:38.181 INFO - Started
> org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@19dda5ce 17:12:38.183 INFO - using the
> json request :
> {"class":"org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest","capabilities":[{"pla
> tform":"VISTA","seleniumProtocol":"Selenium","browserName":"*firefox","maxInstances":5},{"platform":"VISTA","seleniumPro
> tocol":"Selenium","browserName":"*googlechrome","maxInstances":5},{"platform":"VISTA","seleniumProtocol":"Selenium","bro
> wserName":"*iexplore","maxInstances":1},{"platform":"VISTA","seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","browserName":"firefox","maxI
> nstances":5},{"platform":"VISTA","seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","browserName":"chrome","maxInstances":5},{"platform":"WI
> NDOWS","seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","browserName":"internet
> explorer","maxInstances":1}],"configuration":{"port":5555,
> "register":true,"host":"192.168.55.94","proxy":"org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy","maxSession":5,"hubHo
> st":"192.168.55.209","role":"node","registerCycle":5000,"hub":"http://192.168.55.209:4444/grid/register","hubPort":4444,
> "url":"http://192.168.55.94:5555","remoteHost":"http://192.168.55.94:5555"}}
> 17:12:38.185 INFO - starting auto register thread. Will try to
> register every 5000 ms. 17:12:38.185 INFO - Registering the node to
> hub :http://192.168.55.209:4444/grid/register 17:12:38.189 INFO -
> couldn't register this node : Error sending the registration request.
> 17:12:43.194 INFO - couldn't register this node : hub down or not
> responding. 17:12:48.197 INFO - couldn't register this node : hub down
> or not responding.
```

Comment: What happens if you try to hit http://192.168.55.209:4444 from a browser on your client machine?

Comment: I got HTTP ERROR: 403 Forbidden for Proxy Request URI=/

Comment: But http://192.168.55.209:4444/wd/hub works. I got the page for manage the Session.

Answer (score 1):

I know this problem is a few months old, but I had the same issue and was able to clear it up by opening that port for the hub in my firewall settings in AWS.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to start the hub. Type in your command line "java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role hub" and then open another terminal and type your command "java -jar "selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar" \ -role node -port 5555 -hub http://192.168.55.209:4444/grid/register \browser browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOW"